# Specific widths between spans in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site using Bootstrap 2.3 responsive with some basic jQuery involved.

I have 3 buy buttons, all in separate their own span2. The middle buy stays centered, which is what I want, but the buy left and right both move as the browser width is changed.

Is there any way to keep the buy left and right a fixed distance from the center?

Also, I need them in separate spans as the jQuery needs this. (I'm making the buy left and right buttons disappear and being in separate spans keeps the middle buy central.)

```
             <div class="row-fluid buy-row">
                    <div class="span2 offset3"><a href="http://www.reddit.com" class="buy-left">Buy</a></div>
                    <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="#" class="buy-center">Buy</a></div>
                    <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="http://www.soundcloud.com" class="buy-right">Buy</a></div> 
       </div>
```

Edit: To see what I'm talking about in action, check [shifteddd](http://www.shifteddd.com). I want the buy links to remain below their respective poster at all times (well, down to 840px anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fHDxk/4

```
.center-wrap {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.center-wrap .span2 {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px; /* adjust to your taste */
    width: 100px; /* adjust to your taste */
}

<div class="row-fluid buy-row">
    <div class="center-wrap">
        <div class="span2"><a href="http://www.reddit.com" class="buy-left">Click me</a>

        </div>
        <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="#" class="buy-center">Click me</a>

        </div>
        <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="http://www.soundcloud.com" class="buy-right">Click me</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I've removed your offset class.

Comment: That gives me the same result as what I've already got. If you resize the width of the results window of jsfiddle you can see that the distance between each click button changes with the width. I want the center button to remain central at all times. Then I want the buy left and right to remain a fixed width distance from the center.

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem. See this pic to understand me. I want the two dimensions to remain equal, not different like they currently are. i.imgur.com/jQgP7VU.png

Comment: Then add a fixed width to .span2.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much for all the help! Would you mind adding that jsfiddle to your original answer so I can accept your original answer? Thanks again, you've made my day!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you properly you wish for the middle button to not allow the left or right buttons to come within a fixed distance as well as not change location when the browser is expanded, is that correct? If so this is what I see as your solution:

1: Give the center div an additional class as to separate it's CSS with a fixed space between the outer left and right buttons

```
  <div class="row-fluid buy-row">
                <div class="span2 offset3"><a href="http://www.reddit.com" class="buy-left">Buy</a></div>
                <div class="span2 pagination-centered center-button"><a href="#" class="buy-center">Buy</a></div>
                <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="http://www.soundcloud.com" class="buy-right">Buy</a></div> 
   </div>
```

And your CSS for the .center-button class will look like:

```
.center-button{margin:0 15px 0;}
```

And this will cover the left and right spaces preventing both from collapsing onto the center div.

Now your issue with both buttons expanding away from the center, that will be as simple as wrapping the 3 buttons in an additional div and setting a fixed width on the div inside of the 'row-fluid buy-row' for example

```
<div class="row-fluid buy-row">
  <div class="fixed-buy"><!-- additional div wrap to create permanent unchanging width from center -->
                <div class="span2 offset3"><a href="http://www.reddit.com" class="buy-left">Buy</a></div>
                <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="#" class="buy-center">Buy</a></div>
                <div class="span2 pagination-centered"><a href="http://www.soundcloud.com" class="buy-right">Buy</a></div> 
  </div><!-- end your new div -->
</div>
```

Then set your div to the desired pixels you wish to not exceed allowing it to neither expand beyond center or collapse upon it

```
.fixed-buy{width:450px} /* or whichever pixel width you prefer */
```

Does this answer your question?

Additional media queries may need to be set for this fixed position or you could as well do it in percentages or em

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: That's half of it, yes. Now the buys stay a fixed width from eachother, but they don't move at all. How would I keep the center buy central too? At the moment they're all just off to the left.

Comment: Have you tried the jsFiddle above from user Isherwood? I may be misunderstanding your goal as the code in the jsFiddle appears to do what it is the aim you articulate

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem. See this pic to understand me. I want the two dimensions to remain equal, not different like they currently are. http://i.imgur.com/jQgP7VU.png