# How to center two spans within a row in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting two span6 divs to center in Bootstrap. I have these two divs within a single row within a container-fluid but everything sticks to the left. I want the two divs to appear next to each other and centered if possible, but if the screen is too small, I want the second span to go underneath the first one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395367/specific-widths-between-spans-in-bootstrap/15395632#15395632

Answer (score 1):

By default, your markup would need to look something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6"></div>
        <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6"></div>
        <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to make the second `.span6` appear below the first you'd probably want to use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to change the size of the `.container-fluid` container and give the `.span*` classes a minimum width - so that ultimately when the container isn't wide enough to fit both `.span6` elements the second is forced below the first.

Comment: My markup is the same as the first one, but the two spans appear left-aligned for some reason.

Comment: Is this a text alignment issue? In that case, simply use `text-align:center;`. I'd add a new class to achieve this: HTML: `<div class="span6 myClass">` CSS: `.myClass { text-align:center; }`.

Comment: I don't think so. The divs themselves appear to be left-aligned.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm not too sure what you mean by "left-aligned" if you're not talking about the content within.

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/BByL7/

And here's the full-screen result: http://jsfiddle.net/BByL7/embedded/result/

Comment: Ah, you may want to take a look at Bootstrap's [Responsive Scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) section. http://jsfiddle.net/BByL7/2/